# After AdMob implementation the app is very slow even on new devices

Tags: android, admob

After AdMob implementation the app is very slow even on new devices. I tested it mainly on Samsung Galaxy S III mini & Samsung Galaxy S4 BE. Everything have made according to AdMob's guide. onDestroy, onResume, onPause are like in their manual. I`m using AdView in Fragment. Can you give me an advice?
Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: try handlers to load ads.

Comment: Define very slow. Provide some metrics that quantify slowness before and after adding Admob.

Answer (score 0):

load all **ADS** in other ***thread***... currently you are doing it in **UI thread**..